# How to validate date using reactive form in angular if user select date greater than today date

Tags: angular

Cam anybody suggest How to validate date using reactive form in angular if  user select date  greater than today date. I want to show error message .If user select greater than today date

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to prevent/disable users to select a date greater than today?

Comment: @vinay Somawat need to show error message if user select greater than today date

Comment: You can put onchange Event in the input date tag. It will be triggered once the user selects a date then you can validate the selected date and show an error.

Let me know if you want a source code.

Comment: Also please put yourr template code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* reactively set a validator for min and max dates based off of the current date although no default Angular validator currently exists. You'll need to create a custom validator..

```ts
import { FormControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export class DateValidator {

   static LessThanToday(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        let today : Date = new Date();

       if (new Date(control.value) > today)
           return { "LessThanToday": true };

       return null;
   }
}
```

Import the DateValidator class into your component where the reactive form is created, and apply the validator described above. (It may need tweaking, I've not tested it..)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `min` and `max` attributes of the date inputs in your HTML, otherwise, you can only solely use Reactive Forms for validating the presence of the date values i.e. `Validators.required`.

Import the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` and provide `DatePipe` in the `app.module.ts`

`app.module.ts`

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    DatePipe,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Use the `DatePipe` in the `app.component` (or the component you want it) to set the current date and format the date values. Set the default date values in the `ngOnInit` function. Use a form as the parent element of the inputs (not necessary though).

`app.component.ts`

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  maxDate: string;

  constructor(datePipe: DatePipe) {
    const dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
    this.startDate = datePipe.transform(
      new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1),
      dateFormat
    );
    this.maxDate = this.endDate = datePipe.transform(new Date(), dateFormat);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      startDate: new FormControl(this.startDate, Validators.required),
      endDate: new FormControl(this.endDate, Validators.required),
    });
  }

  onDateChange(): void {
    this.startDate = this.form.get('startDate').value;
    this.endDate = this.form.get('endDate').value;
    // some other important code here...
  }  
}
```

In the HTML file, set the `max` attribute of the `startDate` date input to not exceed the `endDate` date input value; and vice-versa: set the `min` attribute of the `endDate` date input to not go beyond the `startDate` date input value

`app.component.html`

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <div>
      <label for="start_date">Start date</label>
      <input id="start_date" type="date" [max]="maxDate > endDate ? endDate : maxDate" (change)="onDateChange()" formControlName="startDate">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="end_date">End date</label>
      <input id="end_date" type="date" [min]="startDate" [max]="maxDate" (change)="onDateChange()" formControlName="endDate">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through these simple steps for validate date using rective form in angular.
In HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroupName">
    <input type="date" formControlName="fromDate"
           [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.fromDate.errors }" required>
    // class is-invalid to show error on input date
</form>
```

Import AbstractControl using

```
import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, ... } from '@angular/forms';
```

Custom validation function above Component

```
export function validateTypeDate(control: AbstractControl) {
  const value = control.value;
  //min date 01/01/1850 and max date today
  if (value == null || value == '' || value <= '1850-01-01' || value > (new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0])) {
    return { required: true };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Reactive form group

```
formGroupName = this.fb.group({
    ..........,
    fromDate: ['', [Validators.required, validateTypeDate]],
    ..........
  });
```